# If column has 'NULL' then select that row of data

Tags: javascript, plotly.js

I have an html table that was read in from a csv using plotly.js. I am graphing this table using plotly and trying to make 'NULL' values stand out in the graph. I was attempting to iterate through the table to find all NULL values and the row they are on. 
I've tried something like

```
var nullValue = [];

for (var j = 0; j < secondCellVal.length; j ++) {
  if (secondGraphData[1] == 'NULL') {
    nullValue.push(secondGraphData[1][j])
  }
}
```

This doesn't work. Hint: the 'NULL' values I am looking for are in the 2nd column of the table I am trying to graph

Answer (score 2):

You're using string comparison when you should just be comparing it by it's literal type (`null`):

```
if (secondGraphData[1] === null) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I think it is a string though. Even so, what is the best way to push the data to the blank array?

Comment: Alternatively you could use `filter` and check for null values that way: `secondGraphData.filter(data => data === 'NULL');`